# How to make custom button and cell shading for moving rows in UITable?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can make custom button for moving rows in UITable?

I would like it to be transparent. 
(Instead of this: [image] )

Another thing is, when the cell is moved, it has shadow. Is it possible to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

**You have to do this by subclassing UITableViewCell and overriding its setEditing:animated: method as follows:**

The re-order control is a UITableViewCellReorderControl, but that's a private class, so you can't access it directly.

you could just look through the hierarchy of subviews and find its imageView.

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing: editing animated: YES];

    if (editing) {

        for (UIView * view in self.subviews) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) rangeOfString: @"Reorder"].location != NSNotFound) {
                for (UIView * subview in view.subviews) {
                    if ([subview isKindOfClass: [UIImageView class]]) {
                        ((UIImageView *)subview).image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"yourimage.png"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have an error on the line: "for (UIView * view in self.subviews)"
It sais- "Property 'subviews' not found on object of type myController"

Comment: Read the Text which i highlight in bold. i think you have wrote this method..in your view controller.....where you have written tableview methods.

Comment: Have you a solution for ios 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the reordering control by setting `-[UITableViewCell setShowsReorderControl:]` to NO. After that you will need your own custom reordering implementation. I'm not sure what you can do about the shadow effect during a move.

If you really want to dig deep you can create your custom table view cell move UX.

Comment: If I'll set setShowsReorderControl to NO. I won't be able to edit, or would I?

Comment: @Luda You have to roll your own move. Attach a UIPanGestureRecognizer to a cell, on first touch remove that cell from the table, add the cell to the windows right where the user is touching it. As the user pans move the cell to keep it under the user's finger.

Comment: @Luda I didn't say it would be easy.